# file system sync between the server and the iphone client

Tags: iphone, synchronization

I have my server maintaining the content with a file-system(i mean folder structure). The same folder structure is also maintained in my iPhone client application bundle too.

Now if there is a change in my server file system(Add,Delete,Update of a file in some folder in the hierarchy) i need to update the file system accordingly at the client. This means that i need a protocol to be followed b/w the server and the client.

Can any one suggest how can this be done?

--
Thanks and Regards,
U'suf

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, there is no easy way. I was looking for an rsync equivalent, but I haven't found one.

In my case, I'm manually walking the tree asking the server for differences after a certain date and I remember the last successful sync date.

Not pretty. Could spend lots of time coming up with something sophisticated.